# ¿Cómo puedo evitar el cierre de un MaterialAlertDialogBuilder al seleccionar el PositiveButton?

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en android la cual en una parte muestra un `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`. Dentro de este solo hay un `TextInputLayout` con su `TextInputEditText`, y dentro del evento de `.setPositiveButton` que tiene el dialog tengo un condicional que comprueba que el campo esté lleno. Cuando el usuario introduce texto este funciona correctamente, se cierra el diálogo y guarda el dato en un `SharedPreferences`, **pero cuando este no introduce nada quisiera que el diálogo no se cierre**, lo demás ya lo tengo hecho. Este es mi código:

```
 //Crear la vista para dialog_item:
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_item, null)


            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                .setView(view)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.title_dialog))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Confirmar")  { dialog, which ->
                    //Guardar el username del TextInputEditText
                    val username = view.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.TIET_dialog).text.toString()

                    //Comprobar que no esté vacío.
                    if(username.trim().isEmpty()){

                        view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.TIL_dialog).error = getString(R.string.error_empty_text)
                        //TODO: -----> Que no se cierre el dialog. <-----

                    }else{

                        //Guardar el dato del nombre
                        spITEM.putString(getString(R.string.key_username), username)
                    }
                }
                .show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes crear el *postive button* con un listener vacío (`{ _, _ -> }`)  y luego reemplazarlo por uno creado directamente sobre el botón. De esta forma el dialog no se cierra automáticamente, por lo que deberás invertir la lógica. En vez de evitar el cierre en el `if`, provócalo en el `else`. Ejemplo:

```
val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
    .setView(view)
    .setTitle(R.string.title_dialog)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Confirmar") { _, _ -> }
    .show()
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener {
    //Guardar el username del TextInputEditText
    val username = view.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.TIET_dialog).text.toString()
    //Comprobar que no esté vacío.
    if (username.trim().isEmpty()) {
        view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.TIL_dialog).error = getString(R.string.error_empty_text)
    } else {
        //Guardar el dato del nombre
        spITEM.putString(getString(R.string.key_username), username)
        // cerrar el dialog
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```